# How to specify the location of a function inside a document with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, document.write

I have a function to write an element inside an html document as follows:

```
function writeFooter(){
return "<div id='div3'><div class='down'>This is my footer</div></div>";}
self.document.writeln (writeFooter ());
```

The script is written in a document called footer.js and added at the head of the document as follows:

```
<script src="footer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As the div id 3 is a footer it has the following style:

```
#div3{position: relative; 
clear: both;}
```

The javascript function works properly but the element is written at the top of the document (right after the body) as below:

```
<body>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

However, the div3 is meant to clear div1 and div2. Is there a way I can specify where this function will be written inside the document so that I have the following result?

```
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`. Use DOM functions like `document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

> The script is written in a document called footer.js and added at the head of the document

That's the problem, because `document.writeln` outputs to the parsing stream at that point. Instead, include it at the location in the document where you want the footer to appear. There are very, very few use cases for putting `script` elements in the `head`; a footer script probably isn't among them. :-)

But if it *absolutely* has to be in the `head`, as you've tagged your question jQuery, you can use jQuery's `ready` callback to make your code wait until the document has been fully-parsed:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("<div id='div3'><div class='down'>This is my footer</div></div>").insertAfter("#div2");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

document.writeln outputs into the document 'in place' when it is called. So if your script tags are in the head, or immediately after the body opening tag, that's where the text will be inserted into the document. Either move your script section, or use the DOM functions to insert the element exactly where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following things:

1) Modify your `footer.js` as:

```
   function writeFooter()
   {
      return "<div id='3'><div class='down'>This is my footer</div></div>";
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("body").append(writeFooter());
   });
```

2) modify your HTML as :

```
    <body>
      <div id="1">one</div>
      <div id="2">two</div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Hi there! div3 is a new div which has to be added to more than 50 files. I don't want to edit each file mannually so I wrote the function in the main javascript file (which is called in the head of all 50 files). Any other suggestion?

Comment: updated the answer. You will have to use `$(document).ready()` handler to achieve this. Now your HTML is free from `<script>` code.